# How to insert data that is condensed ( object type ) in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was able to condense one Row of several columns into one column through function object_construct_keep_null.

```
Source table :
A|B|
---|---
xxx|ABC
yyy|DEF
zzz|GHI
        
DESTINATION table :
object construct keep null(*)| 
 -------- 
{ "A": "xxx", "B": "ABC" }|
{ "A": "yyy", "B": "DEF" }|
{ "A": "zzz", "B": "GHI" }|
```

**But what should I do to make it the opposite without knowing columns?**

Using the 'flatten' function, keys and values are separated, making it difficult to put them in the existing Source table.

Comment: I assume you want to "use the same block to unpack many tables" without having the block know the tables, because it seems like it would be easy to unpack from objects straight into real tables for "free".

Answer (score 0):

so if we have data like:

```
with data(val_a, val_b, cal_c) as (
    select * from values
    (100, 44399579, 'blog1' ),
    (1000, 44399579, 'blog1'),
    (200, 44399579, 'blog2'),
    (2000, 44399579, 'blog2')
)
```

your columns to object:

```
select a.*
    ,object_construct_keep_null(a.*) as obj
from data as a;
```

gives:

| VAL_A | VAL_B | CAL_C | OBJ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 44,399,579 | blog1 | { "CAL_C": "blog1", "VAL_A": 100, "VAL_B": 44399579 } |
| 1,000 | 44,399,579 | blog1 | { "CAL_C": "blog1", "VAL_A": 1000, "VAL_B": 44399579 } |
| 200 | 44,399,579 | blog2 | { "CAL_C": "blog2", "VAL_A": 200, "VAL_B": 44399579 } |
| 2,000 | 44,399,579 | blog2 | { "CAL_C": "blog2", "VAL_A": 2000, "VAL_B": 44399579 } |

thus how to unpack `obj` we access the object explicitly:

```
select 
    b.obj:"VAL_A"::number as val_a
    ,b.obj:"VAL_B"::number as val_b
    ,b.obj:"CAL_C"::text as cal_c
from (
    select a.*
        ,object_construct_keep_null(a.*) as obj
    from data as a
) as b;
```

giving:

| VAL_A | VAL_B | CAL_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 44,399,579 | blog1 |
| 1,000 | 44,399,579 | blog1 |
| 200 | 44,399,579 | blog2 |
| 2,000 | 44,399,579 | blog2 |

I am guess what you want is the columns to be unpacked without knowing the column names ahead of time, but that I don't know how todo without dynamic SQL.